Can you conjugate しておく into しておいています?
Can I change Vておきます into Vておいています to indicate that I am currently doing this preparatory action?
e.g.
明日の試験を合格するために勉強しておきます。⇒
明日の試験を合格するために勉強しておいています。
This may be a silly question, as I know that in theory it is the correct conjugation, however, I have never seen this conjugation used before so I am unsure.

No, you cannot. おく behaves as an instant state-change (aka punctual) verb, so it doesn't have a progressive meaning. Even as a plain verb, 花瓶を置いています means "I have placed a vase (somewhere)" rather than "I am (currently) placing a vase". In your case, just saying 勉強しています is sufficient, but when you really need to express "I am currently doing something in advance", you can use the adverb あらかじめ, which can be straightforwardly combined with a progressive verb.
You might ask: Then can 勉強しておいています mean "I have already studied in advance"? The answer is no again. For this purpose, we almost always use (-て)ある, like this:

❌ 勉強しておいています。(highly unnatural)
✅ 勉強してあります。
I (already) have studied (in advance).

By the way, 合格する is an intransitive verb, so you need to say 試験に合格する.
